# Dynamic url_for with varying amount of nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a helper method that allows me to pass an array with options I would like to be available for the management of an object (like edit, delete, etc.). A simplified version of the method looks like this:

```
  def management_links(instance, actions, *parent)
    actions.each do |action|
      if (can? action, instance)
        has_options = true
        case action
          when :destroy
            options = {content: glyphicon('trash') + " Delete #{instance.class.to_s}", class: "delete #{instance.class.to_s.downcase}", method: :delete}
            url = url_for [parent, instance]
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

As you can see this works perfectly for objects that are nested once (passing 1 parent model) to get the structure:

parent_model/parent_id/model/id/action

But now I have a model that is nested twice, so this won't cut it anymore. I tried passing an array [@grandparent, @parent], but that doesn't work since the url_for already has an array.

Is there some way to allow me passing 'unlimited' parent objects to work with the url_for?

Comment: Very interesting question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*parent` will always be part of an array (if present), so why not declare it as such and then push instance into it:

```
def management_links(instance, actions, *parent)
    parents = Array(parent) if parent
    new_url = parents ? parents << instance : instance

    actions.each do |action|
      if (can? action, instance)
        has_options = true
        case action
          when :destroy
            options = {content: glyphicon('trash') + " Delete #{instance.class.to_s}", class: "delete #{instance.class.to_s.downcase}", method: :delete}
            url = url_for new_url
        end
      end
    end
end
```

I use `Array()` to ensure that `parent` is the correct data type (you may pass a single instance of the var).

---

Off topic, but in the pursuit of [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), you should read up about [nesting by more than one layer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting):

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.

Comment: But nesting 2 levels seems pretty logical when you're building a e-learning system, courses -> modules -> lessons. Or am I missing something? I'm gonna try your solution, looks promising!

Comment: It's up to you, it's not my app - just giving you a reference from the docs. By all means do it if you feel it appropriate :)

Comment: Thanks, I am interested to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, had to use some other tricks, but this was the push in the right direction. Thanks!